# Error replacing legacy provider in Terraform: "Found unresolvable legacy provider references in state"

Tags: terraform, kong

I'm encountering an issue when using the Terraform state replace-provider command to replace a legacy provider in Terraform. I'm receiving the following error: "Found unresolvable legacy provider references in state". I have correctly added the command to my deploy script and verified that the custom provider is configured correctly.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue or have any suggestions for investigating the root cause?

Below my deploy.sh script

> ```
> # DEPLOY
> cd deployment
> terraform init -backend-config="key=spa_$TF_VAR_stage" -backend-config="bucket=$TERRAFORM_STATE_S3_BUCKET"
> terraform state replace-provider registry.terraform.io/-/kong registry.terraform.io/kevholditch/kong
> terraform validate
> terraform plan | grep -v 'environment.'
> terraform apply -auto-approve | grep -v 'environment.\|.env'
> ```

The error from deployment

```
Error: Failed to install legacy providers required by state
Found unresolvable legacy provider references in state. It looks like these
refer to in-house providers. You can update the resources in state with the
following command:
    terraform state replace-provider registry.terraform.io/-/kong registry.terraform.io/kevholditch/kong
```

My version.tf

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.28.0"
    }
    kong = {
      source = "kevholditch/kong"
      version = "~> 6.5.0"
    }
    null = {
      source  = "hashicorp/null"
      version = "~> 2.1"
    }
    random = {
      source  = "hashicorp/random"
      version = "~> 2.2"
    }
    vault = {
      source  = "hashicorp/vault"
      version = "~> 2.10"
    }
  }
  required_version = ">= 0.13"
}
```

I'm updating the terraform 0.12 to 0.13

Comment: Unfortunately v0.13 is now pretty old and so it's hard to remember the different error cases for this upgrade, but I _think_ what you tried here ought to have worked and so something unusual seems to be going on. Can you run `terraform providers` with Terraform CLI v0.13 and edit your question to include the result? That might give a clue.

Comment: @MartinAtkins I finally managed it :) I updated 0.12 > 0.13 then updated to the latest one 1.5.3 and I updated the Kong provider for the latest version, it worked. Thank you for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I need to keep always updated the terraform

I’ve been updated 0.12 to 0.13 then used the command

> terraform validate

After, no errors, I’ve updated direct to the latest version of terraform 1.5.3 and updated every providers